# How to change HTML tags and attributes using PHP in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, image, wordpress

In my wordpress blog I'm trying to set up a code/a function to turn every image in a post into a thumbnail using the `phpThumbnail` library.

So far I have this function which generates an array of images in a post and creates a thumbnail out of the first image using the `_thumbnail_id` meta key.

```
function sThumbnail() {
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$post = get_post($post_id);
$first_img = '';
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
$first_img = $matches[1][0];

var_dump($matches);

$first_img = substr($first_img, strlen(site_url()));

$post_thumbnail = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', true );

if (!wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) { // Verify that post is not a revision
    if (empty($post_thumbnail)) {       // Check if Thumbnail does NOT exist!
          if(empty($first_img)){
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', 'http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/About/General/2012/11/1/1351779022327/Nicki-Minaj---You-ve-neve-010.jpg' );
          } else {
              update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $first_img );
          } // Get the first image of a post (if available)
    }
}
}
```

With some modification I could use the function to get all of the images in a post and then do something with them.
The problem is that I have no idea how to alter the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag or delete it and enter a new one.

Basically, all I need is that 1-2 lines that alter the `src` attribute or some general info about how to alter/play with tags and their attributes.

Some points:
- Just to clarify, by `src`, I mean `<img src="..." />`.
- The function above is **NOT** the function I'm going to use!
It's merely for reference as the first 6/7 lines of it are the way to get the content of the `src` attribute of an **image** tag.

Comment: What could you possibly be hoping to achieve by calling `ob_start` and then immediately calling `ob_end_clean`?

Comment: I don't think so. The function I posted is used only for reference to show that I know how to get the `src` attribute of an image, but not how to change it. Which is exactly what I'm asking about.

Comment: Madbreaks is just telling you your code is doing something absurd. It opens the "output buffer" (ob_start) and immediately after, it clears it and closes it. Whether or not you are using it... it still is absurd. And just as absurd is to have get_the_ID() (which means you already have the "post") just followed by $post = get_post($post_id);... This code is completely incoherent. Where did you find it?

Comment: Ohhh sorry! I probably misread his comment...
This is a code I put up from this both links: http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-define-a-default-post-thumbnail and http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-get-the-first-image-from-the-post-and-display-it . `The get_the_ID()` part is actually my fault. Thanks for noting that out! I'll fix it immediately!

Comment: By the way, I used the `publish_post` wordpress hook and it returns an ID, not a post. Thus, it required me to use `get_the_ID()`, even though I now know I should have set the function to receive an `id` variable (`sThumbnail($post_id)`)